# Quarter turn valve only moves when nothing connected

Tags: plumbing, valve, stuck

I'm trying to connect a new dishwasher in a house we just moved into. The problem I'm having is that the quarter turn valve that was already in place on the pipe that was already there for the dishwasher (the previous owner took away the dishwasher) won't move to allow me to turn on the water after everything is connected to the new dishwasher. With nothing connected it will turn and open the valve. I tried turning off the water at the main valve, but it didn't make a difference. What could be blocking this valve from moving? It turns slightly before stopping.[image]

Comment: How about a picture. Is the connecting nut hitting the handle?

Comment: Is the handle secure to the shaft?

Comment: Try if it is a push-turn or pull-turn valve.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if your main shutoff fails, then you'd be stuck with the water to the dishwasher turned on, which sort of defeats the purpose of having a shutoff there. Is there any way you can remove the blue handle and reposition it or shave plastic so that it works?

Comment: Oh, and keep an eye on the plumbing for a few months... teflon tape on a compression fitting is unconventional at best.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the compression nut at the inlet of the quarter turn valve to see if the old owner pushed the copper pipe too far into the valve. If that is not why the valve will not turn then I would just replace the valve.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly issue where the blue knob was hitting off the fitting. I ended up turning off the mains, opening the cutoff valve, connecting the dishwasher and then turning back on the mains. So far so good, but the cutoff now can't be turned off without removing the dishwasher connection first. Not ideal, but good enough for now.